# jQuery - select table cells without selecting from a nested table

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I wrote some jQuery to select the cells from a table with a certain class; in this case, "hello".  However, the table has nested tables with a column of the same class.  How do I select the cells from the outer table but not select the cells from the inner? See below:

```
HTML:
<table class="foo"> <!-- this is the outer table
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="hello"> <!-- select this cell

        <table> <!-- this is the nested table
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td class="hello"> <!-- do not select this cell
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>

      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

jQuery:
// this selects the nested cells as well
$('table.foo:first').find('td.hello').doSomething();
```

Comment: Something like `$('table:first tbody tr td.hello').doSomething();`

Comment: @Chad: This wouldn't work. It will select all descendant `tbody` s and therefore all `td` s.

Comment: @Felix Kling, Right, I should have had `>` between each element in the selector

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want is to avoid recursing too deeply, so you can go like this:

`$('table:first > tbody > tr > td.hello')`

Which, I believe, is equivalent to

`$('table:first').children('tbody').children('tr').children('td.hello')`

Comment: Whether your <tr>s are inside tbody or not, you have to use tbody selector.

Answer (score 0):

If the classes on the outer table stay, you can just use:

```
$('table.foo > tbody > tr > td.hello');
```

One thing to note here perhaps is the fact that the `<tbody>` element is **always** present, even if you do not specify it explicitly. Due to the nature of the SGML/HTML/XHTML/whatyacallit definition for the `<tbody>` element, it has a *optional* opening tag. Even if the source does not contain it, the DOM element will be created when parsing the table.

Comment: I seem to remember there was some ambiguity about the autopresence of the tbody element in earlier versions of internet explorer. Does anybody happen to have a definitive reference about that?